# data posting to url in phoneGap

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http, cordova

We need TWO STRING value Pass to JSON.String Value like this

```
stringone = " [ {\"totalamount\": 19760,\"discount\": 7,\"NetAmount\": 18377,\"vat\":8,\"GrossAmount\":8,\"bookOrder\": \"ABCANG00110\" }, {\"totalamount\": 1960,\"discount\": 7,\"NetAmount\": 1377,\"vat\":7,\"GrossAmount\":7,\"bookOrder\": \"ABCG00110\" }]";

stringtwo = "[ {\"items\": 19760,\"descriptions\": 7,\"umo\": 18377,\"qty\":8,\"price\":8,\"lineamount\": \"22\" ,\"customerid\": 1960,\"tdate\": 7,\"orderId\": 1377,\"bookorder\":7,\"FOC\":7 }]";
```

We tried like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://183.82.0.221:1234/MyService.svc/PostOrderData/'+stringone+','+stringtwo+'',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type:'get',
    cache:false,
    timeout: 2000,
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t=="timeout") {
            alert("this app need internet connection so Please connect net first ");
        } else {
            //alert(t);
        }
    },
    success:function(data) {
        debugger;
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

But `alert("this app need internet connection so Please connect net first ");` is shown and status is 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are receiving status code 400 from the server. Status code 400 stands for (source: [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1))

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

In your case the problem is the format of URL at least. According to your own server in address (can't link into it normally because of SO..)

```
http://183.82.0.221:1234/MyService.svc

You can also access the service description as a single file:
http://183.82.0.221:1234/MyService.svc?singleWsdl
```

which means that you shouldn't use */* on your URL after MyService. Also, you should pass the JSONs as URL parameters with syntax

```
http://183.82.0.221:1234/MyService.svc?PostOrderData&stringone=<value of stringone here>&stringtwo=<value of stringtwo here>
```

which is now the URL you should be using.

Also, to use jsonp, your server would need to respond with JavaScript, which it doesn't and thus parse error is generated by *ajax* response. You should look into [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org) on how to enable cross-origin requests and use plain AJAX.

So to conclude:

1. Enable CORS and disable JSONP (or then make your server response with JavaScript).
2. Change the GET URL to be like shown earlier.
3. Use `JSON.stringify` to make the JSON strings from objects instead of making those manually with backslashes ().

Start with these and make a new question once you face next problem with this since it has so many problems in it, unfortunately. Good luck!